# Java Matrix with Generic / Bounded Wildcard Inputs

Tags: java, generics, syntax, wildcard

I'd like to create a class `Matrix` that accepts objects of type `T extends Item` for a game inventory. However, I'm having issues with implementing the class using generics / wildcards. This is what I have so far.

```
public class Matrix<T> {
    private final int maxVertical;
    private final int maxHorizontal;

    private T[][] contents;


    public <T extends Item> Matrix(int maxVertical, int maxHorizontal) {
         this.maxVertical = maxVertical;
         this.maxHorizontal = maxHorizontal;

         contents = new T[maxVertical][maxHorizontal];
    }
```

Comment: "I'm having issues" What issues?

Comment: Syntax issues in the IDE, specifically in the `contents` initialisation (last line of constructor)

Comment: Is there a way to create a constructor for a generic class without having an instance of the generic as a parameter as is shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: Did you look at _all_ the answers in the dupe? Look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2924453/5133585) by dimo414, and its comment section too.